# How to include static files content in chef templates

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have a template which is trying to include `.conf` files from a folder. I have the following line in my template abc.conf.erb

```
include /tmp/config.d/*.conf
```

And inside /tmp/config.d I have multiple `.conf` files. I want to fetch content of all the .conf files in the directory and include statement in abc.conf file. I also tried

```
include=/tmp/config.d/*.conf
```

when I run the recipe the template simply has the same include written in it. Here is the recipe source code

```
template '/tmp/config.d/abc.conf' do
  source 'abc.conf.erb'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Chef has nothing in particular for this. You would have to build it yourself using the normal Ruby file APIs.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the contents of the files in that directory inside your template file, for example:

```
<% Dir["/tmp/config.d/*.conf"].each do |f| -%>
<%= ::File.read(f) %>
<% end %>
```

This should combine all the `.conf` file contents inside `config.d` into one file.